# Iterator for const list<t> in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote this non-member function for finding `member`s with the maximum and minimum values of `level` (a `float` property). My logic is push back all `level`s from `vipList` to a vector, and calculate using `std::max_element` and `std::min_element`, and return a `std::pair` that contains those 2 values:

```
pair<float,float> minMax (const list<member>& vipList){
    vector<float> v(vipList.size());
    for (list<member>::iterator it = vipList.begin(); it!=vipList.end(); ++it) //error
    {
        v.push_back(it->level);
    }
    return std::make_pair(*std::max_element(std::begin(v),std::end(v)),*std::min_element(std::begin(v),std::end(v)));
}
```

the error message is:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<member>>>" to "std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<member>>>" exists
```

So I changed `list<member>::iterator it` to `std::_List_const_iterator<member> it` and that does not work either. If I remove `const` from the parameter, it builds, but that is not what I wanted. Can some one please help? Thank you.

Comment: use `list<member>::const_iterator` or `auto`. Or for range.

Comment: Note that there is already `std::minmax_element` (with predicate).

Comment: *My logic is push back all levels from vipList to a vector*  -- Wasteful.  Just call `std::minmax_element` using a lambda / predicate on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `vipList` is a `const list<member>&` you need to use `list<member>::const_iterator` as that is what `begin()` will return.  You could also use `auto` and let the compiler pick the right type.

Instead of doing all of this we could just use [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) which will return a pair of iterators the min and max values.  We can do that with the list using a lambda like

```
return std::minmax_element(vipList.begin(), vipList.end(), [](const member & lhs, const member& rhs) { return lhs.level < rhs.level; });
```

This will return a `std::pair<std::list<member>::const_iterator, std::list<member>::const_iterator>`.  If you want it to return a `std::pair<float, float>` then we need to capture the return of `std::minmax_element` and dereference the iterators to get the underlying floats.

```
auto ip = std::minmax_element(vipList.begin(), vipList.end(), [](const member & lhs, const member& rhs) { return lhs.level < rhs.level; });
return std::make_pair(ip.first->level, ip.second->level);
```

Comment: Thanks. it's `begin` not `being`. Also compiler is telling me it's missing a semicolon somewhere.

Comment: @DylanChen Yep.  `begin` was misspelled and I forgot a `;` after `return lhs.level < rhs.level`.  I have updated the code.

Comment: that was what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, you have to dereference iterator and retrieve `level` to return the pair of float.

Comment: @Jarod42 the `make_pair` function seems to return a `pair` of `member`s instead of `float`s. How would you do it?

Comment: @DylanChen The last code block shows how to just return a `pair` of `float`s

Comment: @NathanOliver I see what you are doing and I did it that way and the compiler says "no suitable user-defined conversion from `std::pair<member, member>` to `std::pair<float, float>` exists"

Comment: @DylanChen Oops.  You are right.  I forgot to include the `.level`.  Try it with the updated code.

Comment: Still not working, but I tried `return std::make_pair(ip.first->level, ip.second->level);` and it functions perfectly.

Comment: @DylanChen Sorry about that.  I normally compile this stuff to double check it but I never set up an example for this.  i updated the answer to reflect to correct syntax.  `ip.first->level` or `(*(ip.first)).level` would be correct.